# How to find all elements of a given class not in a particular id container using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Its probably simple but I am not able to do it. I want to find and select all elements of a class which are not contained under a given id.
For Example: Below here, how to find elements of class "me" outside id "con"

```
<div id="con">
    <div class="me">hi1</div>
    <div class="me">hi2</div>
</div>
    <div class="me">hi3</div>
    <div class="me">hi4</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".me").not("#con .me");
```

Using [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) you can specify a selector that the elements should **not** match.

http://jsfiddle.net/AufVD/

---

This could also be written as:

```
$(".me:not(#con .me)");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AufVD/1/

Answer (score -1):

you can use

`$('.me:not(#con)')`​​​

or

```
$('.me').not('#con')
```